# LINQ custom OR operator to aggregate on SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I want to use OR operator on my ints. I can use something like this.

```
new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 8, 24, 32, 56 }.Aggregate((a,b) => a | b)
```

It equals to 63. However, I can't do something like

```
db.numbers.Select(a => a.number).Aggregate((a,b) => a | b)
```

It throws this exception:

> NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Aggregate[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32], System.Func`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.````

I think because it does not know what function in sql server implements `a | b`. I don't know it too.

Is there any way to implement this on without Aggregating it locally?

Comment: It's not `|`, it's `Aggregate` that's not supported. You can see the list of supported and unsupported LINQ methods in LINQ to Entites here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Another option to consider is to write a custom .Net aggregate function and import that DLL into SQL Server itself. I've done many of those and they work well. I'm not sure how to call that from LINQ though, but if the goal is to do the heavy lifting on the SQL side, then it's worth exploring.

Comment: @JosephGagliardo I did similar thing when I was digging mysql, it was only a sql function written in c++. But in this case, I have to tell to Linq that there is a function named "mycustomor" and the most hard part to tell it's an Aggregate function. But it is a great mention, I'll experiment with it when things get complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Aggregate` is not supported by linq-to-entities (regardless of what function you pass in).  Remember that SQL is set-based, so custom aggregations are often *very* difficult to translate to SQL.

You can do the aggregation outside of SQL:

```
db.numbers.Select(a => a.number)
          .AsEnumerable()  // shift from EF to Linq-to-Objects
          .Aggregate((a,b) => a | b)
```

The main difference is that the entire data set will be pulled into memory rather than the result of the aggregation.  If you can figure out a way to do the aggregation in SQL (I can't think of one) then you may have better performance just executing a SQL statement rather than a Linq query.

Comment: I am familiar with AsEnumerable or ToList, however it does not work in subquery under some cases like ````db.table.Select(a => db.anothertable.Select(b => b.number).AsEnumerable().Aggregate((a,b) => a | b))```` unless you don't apply AsEnumerable to the db.table, which can be pain if you have lots of joins (which I have). Since then I'll take and accept this answer as a no because I mentioned "without Aggregating it locally" (for the case I mentioned earlier) in the post. Thanks!